# How can I deal with strings that have reached the 13 character limit where there is no delimiter?

Tags: php

I have several strings that I need to parse. The string is supposed to be delimited with a caret character, however, if the maximum number of allowed characters in the string is reached, the caret character is omitted. I need to find a way to deal with this.

Here is an example.

The rule is that there can be no more than a maximum of 13 characters in it. In the following string, there is an "S" where there should be a caret character.

```
MASSYBU HILLSMARY
```

This is an example of a string that has not reached the 13 character limit

```
CYPRUS^TOM
```

How can I deal with strings that have reached the 13 character limit where there is no delimiter as in the first example?

Comment: Are these strings in one line or broken by return characters? I can't tell if "MASSYBU HILLSMARY" is to become "MASSYBU HILL^" or "MASSYBU HILL^" AND "SMARY".

Comment: Ryan, the string should be, after it is broken down, MASSYBU HILLS MARY. It is the city and the last name of the person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First limit the string to 13 characters (using substr, for example), then look for the terminator. Is that what you're looking for?

Or, if you're looking for the character using indexOf, limit the result to 13. It really depends on what your code looks like.

EDIT: Let me spell it out.

```
$Length = Min(strlen($String), 13);
if (($TerminatorIndex = strpos($String, "^")) !== FALSE) {
  $Length = Min($Length, $TerminatorIndex);
}

return substr($String, 0, $Length);
```

Comment: I had planned to use substr then look backwards for the delimiter. If it's found then handle one way else another. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Added an example implementation. The regex implementation above is nice too.

Comment: Thank you Ebo. Unfortunately, sometimes I need things spelled out for me. :) I believe this will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a job for regular expressions

```
$str = "whatever^abcabcabcabcxABCABCABCABCXDEF^";

preg_match_all('~[^^]{1,13}~', $str, $m);
var_dump($m[0]);
```

outputs

```
  [0]=>  string(8) "whatever"
  [1]=>  string(13) "abcabcabcabcx"
  [2]=>  string(13) "ABCABCABCABCX"
  [3]=>  string(3) "DEF"
```

Comment: Hi stereofrog, thanks for the code snippet. This looks very promising. I'm going to play with this and see if I can get something working. I'll be back in a bit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cut extra characters you can do it like this:

```
$n = 13;

if(strlen($str) > $n)
{
    //do some alteration example
    $str = substr($str, 0, $n);
}
```

Comment: Hey Nazariy, thanks for the code snippet. The problem I'm having is that the string will vary in length depending on the person's city, name etc. I'm not sure that this will get me where I need to be. Basically, it looks like I will need to count off the blocks then look for a carrot character. If the carrot character is not found, then I will need to cut the string at 13.