# Is there a way to parse these strings?

Tags: php

If there is, I certainly don't see it. We are doing magnetic stripe reads off of driver's licenses. The data does not seem to be consistent. The standard that the driver's licenses should follow sets limits on the length that any one field can have. The part that I can't wrap my head around is how to parse this data.

For example, a field may allow 13 total characters but only 8 are used. In this case, there will always be a caret delimiter ending that portion of the string. However, and here is the tricky part, if a field is exactly 13 (of the 13 allowable), there is no end caret delimiter and no right padding. All of the data just runs together.

Here are two sample strings.

```
%CAMISSION HILLSSMITH$JOHN$JIM$JR^1147 SOMESTREET^?
%CALOS ANGELES^DOE$JOHN$CARL^14324 MAIN ST APT 5^?
```

Using PHP, how might I do this? I'd truly appreciate a hand on this. I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, here we go. I used the `x` flag to make the regex more readable and be able to comment it.

From the spec @EboMike posted, each field has a maximum length and is terminated by `^` if it is shorter than that length. The name is a composite field using `$` as a separator between family name, first name, middle name, and suffix. Same goes for the address, which uses `$` if the address has multiple lines.

```
$licenses = array(
    '%CAMISSION HILLSSMITH$JOHN$JIM$JR^1147 SOMESTREET^?',
    '%CALOS ANGELES^DOE$JOHN$CARL^14324 MAIN ST APT 5^?'
);

foreach ($licenses as $license) {
    preg_match(
        '@
            ^%
            (.{2})          # State, 2 chars
            ([^^]{0,12}.)   # City, 13 chars, delimited by ^
            ([^^]{0,34}.)   # Name, 35 chars, delimited by ^
            ([^^]{0,28}.)   # Address, 29 chars, delimited by ^
            \?$
        @x',
        $license,
        $fields
    );

    $state   = $fields[1];
    $city    = rtrim($fields[2], '^');
    $name    = explode('$', rtrim($fields[3], '^'));
    $address = explode('$', rtrim($fields[4], '^'));

    echo "$license\n";
    echo "STATE:   "; print_r($state);   echo "\n";
    echo "CITY:    "; print_r($city);    echo "\n";
    echo "NAME:    "; print_r($name);
    echo "ADDRESS: "; print_r($address);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
CAMISSION HILLSSMITH$JOHN$JIM$JR^1147 SOMESTREET^
STATE:   CA
CITY:    MISSION HILLS
NAME:    Array
(
    [0] => SMITH
    [1] => JOHN
    [2] => JIM
    [3] => JR
)
ADDRESS: Array
(
    [0] => 1147 SOMESTREET
)

CALOS ANGELES^DOE$JOHN$CARL^14324 MAIN ST APT 5^
STATE:   CA
CITY:    LOS ANGELES
NAME:    Array
(
    [0] => DOE
    [1] => JOHN
    [2] => CARL
)
ADDRESS: Array
(
    [0] => 14324 MAIN ST APT 5
)
```

Comment: John, thank you for this. I'm still trying to get this to work. Regex is not my forte. I should have removed the '%' and the '?' as they are not needed. Do I just have to remove those characters from your regex to get this to work?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the `%` from the front and the `\?` from the back if you've already stripped those out.

Comment: OK, John, I removed the '%' as well as the '/?' but I now get an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @John I'm not sure. You changed the `^%` to just `^` and the `\?$` to `$`?

Comment: @John: Stop, you're scaring me. :) OMG: Man, you are unbelievable with this regex. I can't find a flaw in it yet.

Comment: @John. actually, let me give you the exact string as it will be handed off to my class. brb

Comment: OK, this is exactly how it will be passed into my method. CAMISSION HILLSSMITH$JOHN$JIM$JR^1147 SOMESTREET^

Comment: John, you are the man! Honestly, I'd never have been able to do this without everyone's help here, especially you. Man, thank you very much!

Comment: @John Kugelman: your regex was so impressive, I had to open a new StackOverflow question *just* to address all my questions About it!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693861/what-does-it-mean-when-a-regular-expression-is-surrounded-by-symbols

Answer (score 3):

Didn't you ask this question a few hours ago? Someone posted a regex that handles the case where you separate strings that are either delimited or run exactly 13 characters here: [Help with a delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689548/help-with-a-delimited-string/3689621#3689621)

Did that not work?

EDIT: The format is explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card#United_States_driver.27s_licenses

For the city, it says "Field Separator - one character (generally '^') (absent if city reaches max length)". So again, a simple regex can do wonders here. Refer to the example, you can adjust it to match the format as detailed in the entry here.

EDIT: Okay, I'll give it a shot.

```
$str = "%CAMISSION HILLSSMITH$JOHN$JIM$JR^1147 SOMESTREET^?";
preg_match("/%(..)".
           "([^\^]{1,13})\^?".
           "([^\\\$]+)\\\$".
           "([^\\\$]+)\\\$/",
           $str, $m);
$State = $m[1];
$City = $m[2];
$LastName = $m[3];
$FirstName = $m[4];
```

Just as an example of hwo you could go at it.
Basically, `([^\^]{1,13})` means it'll try to get up to 13 characters that are not the '^' character. Once that's done, it'll consume the '^' character itself IF it's there via `\^?`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, it was me. I tried the code that I gave the credit to but it isn't working. I am getting the wrong results. The answer that I accepted does the same thing that the regex does.

Comment: You'll need to adjust it to the format - it's not just 13 characters. See the Wikipedia link I added. The format is well-defined, but it's more than just "every entry is up to 13 characters".

Comment: OK, Ebo, thanks again. I'll give it a shot. Can you confirm that what I need to do is 100% possible? I'm not real strong in string functions and even less in regex.

Comment: It's actually pretty trivial. Btw, here's a link to the original specifications. http://www.aamva.org/aamva/DocumentDisplay.aspx?id={966F5E02-58E1-4935-9F8D-9836A90217FE} ... I might give the regex a shot, at least for the beginning of it.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That document helps. I wish I had time to look at that before I inherited this. What do you think of the solution offered by John K.?

Comment: The magnetic stripe format is in Appendix F.6 of the document @EboMike linked to, page 86.

Comment: Thanks John, I just found it.

Answer (score 2):

Work from left to right, dealing with one field at a time.

Strip off the leading %:

`CAMISSION HILLSSMITH$JOHN$JIM$JR^1147 SOMESTREET^?`

Take the first 15 chars (first field is max. 15 chars, right?):

`CAMISSION HILLS`

Doesn't contain a caret - great that's our first field - the next field starts on 16th char:

`SMITH$JOHN$JIM$JR^1147 SOMESTREET^?`       (R1)

I don't know the max len. of this field - let's assume it's 20.  Take the first 20 chars:

`SMITH$JOHN$JIM$JR^11`

Contains a caret - so we've > 1 field here.  Take the chars up to the caret:

`SMITH$JOHN$JIM$JR`

...that's our next field.  Now grab the string from (R1) above starting on the (length of prev field + 2)th character (+2 to skip over the ^)

`1147 SOMESTREET^?`

etc.

Comment: Thanks Will. The first field is the state and is always 2. That one is easy. The second field is the city. Following that we have the person's name. The last field is the entire address. The first field is 2 chrs. The city field is 13 chars. The name field is 35 chars and the address is 29 chars

Comment: @John: No problem - glad to be of assistance.  The approach given above, whilst not the most efficient way of doing it, does help you logically break it down into manageable chunks - you should find it pretty straightforward to performing the parse in PHP this way.

Comment: Will, thank you for helping me. @xkcd: I just went to your site and saw the regex comic strip on the main page. I'm still laughing. :)

Answer (score 0):

If this were java, I'd solve this with regular expressions.  I know there must be some in PHP?

All the constraints you mentioned can be translated into REGEX.

for example:

```
X{n,m}?      X, at least n but not more than m times
```

can be used with something like:

```
[^%\$\^]{1,13}[%\$\^]
```

Which reads as, "1-13 instances of any character not equal to %, $, or ^ followed by one of those very same delimiters"

When I write regex, I often refer back to [Java's great doc page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).  You can also do neat tricks like extract particular matching portions and pull out particular words.  Again, I'm more familiar with java but PHP is too mature of a language *not* to have the same kinds of features.

I hope that helps in some way.  If no one else answers, I can try to create the regex you need.

- gMale

Comment: gmale, thanks for the code. I'm going to give this a try shortly.