# What does it mean when a regular expression is surrounded by @ symbols?

Tags: php, regex

**Question**

What does it mean when a regular expression is surrounded by @ symbols? Does that mean something different than being surround by slashes?  What about when @x or @i are on the end?  Now that I think about it, what do the surrounding slashes even mean?

---

**Background**

I saw [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690155/is-there-a-way-to-parse-these-strings), posted by John Kugelman, in which he displays serious Regex skills.

Now, I'm used to seeing regexes surrounded by slashes as in

```
/^abc/
```

But he used a regex surrounded by @ symbols:

```
'@
        ^%
        (.{2})          # State, 2 chars
        ([^^]{0,12}.)   # City, 13 chars, delimited by ^
        ([^^]{0,34}.)   # Name, 35 chars, delimited by ^
        ([^^]{0,28}.)   # Address, 29 chars, delimited by ^
        \?$
 @x'
```

In fact, it seems to be in the format:

```
@^abc@x
```

In the process of trying to google what that means (it's a tough question to google!), I also saw the format:

```
@^abc@i
```

It's clear the ***x*** and the ***i*** are not matched characters.

So what does it all mean???

Thanks in advance for any and all responses,

-gMale

Comment: Read in the PHP documentation about delimiters: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php This should make it all clear.

Comment: thanks for the great link. It lead me to another good link that explains all the *pattern modifiers*. I assume all this stuff applies to more than just PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The surrounding slashes are just the regex delimiters. You can use any character (afaik) to do that - the most commonly used is the /, other I've seen somewhat commonly used is #

So in other words, `@whatever@i` is essentially the same as `/whatever/i` (i is modifier for a case-insensitive match)

The reason you might want to use something else than the / is if your regex contains the character. You avoid having to escape it, similar to using '' for strings instead of "".

Comment: Good answer! If *i* is the modifier for case-insensitive search, what is the *x* a modifier for? Do you know of a place that would explain that aspect (the modifiers) in detail?  All the regex stuff I google only covers the basics and I thoroughly know the basics.

Comment: The `x` modifier invokes free-spacing mode: http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html

Comment: @Delan: thanks, that's a fantastic source of advanced Regex information, generic across all languages! I'm adding this as a primary bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

Found this from a "Related" link.

The delimiter can be any character that is not alphanumeric, whitespace or a backslash character.

`/` is the most commonly used delimiter, since it is closely associated with regex literals, for instance in JavaScript where they are the only valid delimiter. However, any symbol can be used.

I have seen people use `~`, `#`, `@`, even `!` to delimit their regexes in a way that avoids using symbols that are also in the regex. Personally I find this ridiculous.

A lesser-known fact is that you can use a matching pair of brackets to delimit a regex in PHP. This has the tremendous advantage of having an obvious difference between the closing delimiter, and the symbol showing up in the pattern, and therefore don't need any escaping. My personal preference is this:

```
(^abc)i
```

By using parentheses, I remind myself that in a match, `$m[0]` is always the full match, and the subpatterns start at `$m[1]`.

Comment: I'm interested in your comment re less conventional delimiters being ridiculous? It strikes me that regexes are difficult to read at the best of times, without adding additional `\/` tokens into the mix. I can see advantage in avoiding alternatives re the compliance with other languages as you've pointed out, but then your own personal preference of using parenthesis negates that compliance too? But +1 for the parenthesis pattern, I think I'll start using it. Although I wonder if it's rarely used and hence even more "obscure" than the other more commonly understood  alternates you highlighted?

Comment: Well, a common usage has to start somewhere, right? ;) You heard it here first! LOL. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: :-) The movement has started! Viva la revolution!

Comment: if alternate delimiters are useful to help avoid escaping slashes, wouldn't using parenthesis as delimiters require the parenthesis in the regex to be escaped? I use parenthesis in regexes *FAR* more often than slashes.

Comment: That's the beauty of it. Parentheses come in pairs, so there's no need to escape them in the pattern.